# Zpool hung while attaching a new disk, now faulted

Tags: arch-linux, software-raid, zfs

I was attempting to expand the storage on a large ZFS pool, adding a similarly sized drive from a USB bay. The pool was in use, and the `zpool attach` command hung. After an hour, it still hadn't returned, so I tried `systemctl reboot`. After a few minutes, I went to check on the server and the monitor I put on it for local troubleshooting had a blank screen with a blinking terminal cursor. Finally, I powered off the machine and powered it back on.

Now, the pool isn't mounting or importing. I have no backup to restore from. If there's any way to recover the metadata, even with partial data loss, I want to try it. This pool's data was built up over years and I'm not even sure I can still find all of the originals.

I tried to force an import with a few commands I was able to find

```
[root@**** ****]# zpool import
   pool: video
     id: 15905175910815917143
  state: FAULTED
status: The pool metadata is corrupted.
 action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
        The pool may be active on another system, but can be imported using
        the '-f' flag.
   see: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/msg/ZFS-8000-72
 config:

        video                                FAULTED  corrupted data
          raidz1-0                           ONLINE
            ata-ST8000DM004-2CX188_ZR10AYT2  ONLINE
            ata-ST8000DM004-2CX188_ZR10AXW8  ONLINE
            ata-ST8000DM004-2CX188_ZR10AXV1  ONLINE
            ata-ST8000DM004-2CX188_ZR10RA7N  ONLINE
            ata-ST8000DM004-2U9188_ZR151F2J  ONLINE
          raidz1-1                           ONLINE
            sdg                              ONLINE
            sdh                              ONLINE
            sdi                              ONLINE
[root@**** ****]# zpool import -f video
cannot import 'video': I/O error
        Destroy and re-create the pool from
        a backup source.
[root@**** ****]# zpool import -F video
cannot import 'video': I/O error
        Destroy and re-create the pool from
        a backup source.
[root@**** ****]# zpool import -FX video
cannot import 'video': one or more devices is currently unavailable
```

[Another question that looked similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66774911/zpool-import-one-or-more-devices-is-currently-unavailable) (thanks review step) used a command I'm not familiar with, but I figured at this point I'm already probably hosed so it can't hurt much more to try it, and it gave information that looks informative but I'm not sure how to parse or what steps to try next.

```
 zdb -e video

Configuration for import:
        version: 5000
        pool_guid: 15905175910815917143
        name: 'video'
        state: 0
        vdev_children: 2
        vdev_tree:
            type: 'root'
            id: 0
            guid: 15905175910815917143
            children[0]:
                type: 'raidz'
                id: 0
                guid: 2054687036979935271
                nparity: 1
                metaslab_array: 256
                metaslab_shift: 34
                ashift: 12
                asize: 32006194855936
                is_log: 0
                create_txg: 4
                children[0]:
                    type: 'disk'
                    id: 0
                    guid: 13972984489407319282
                    whole_disk: 1
                    DTL: 19756
                    create_txg: 4
                    path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST8000DM004-2CX188_ZR10AYT2-part1'
                    devid: 'ata-ST8000DM004-2CX188_ZR10AYT2-part1'
                    phys_path: 'pci-0000:01:00.1-ata-1.0'
                children[1]:
                    type: 'disk'
                    id: 1
                    guid: 3269387665146278941
                    whole_disk: 1
                    DTL: 19755
                    create_txg: 4
                    path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST8000DM004-2CX188_ZR10AXW8-part1'
                    devid: 'ata-ST8000DM004-2CX188_ZR10AXW8-part1'
                    phys_path: 'pci-0000:01:00.1-ata-2.0'
                children[2]:
                    type: 'disk'
                    id: 2
                    guid: 1063598399220908338
                    whole_disk: 1
                    DTL: 19754
                    create_txg: 4
                    path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST8000DM004-2CX188_ZR10AXV1-part1'
                    devid: 'ata-ST8000DM004-2CX188_ZR10AXV1-part1'
                    phys_path: 'pci-0000:01:00.1-ata-3.0'
                children[3]:
                    type: 'disk'
                    id: 3
                    guid: 15825360133242429167
                    whole_disk: 1
                    DTL: 19753
                    create_txg: 4
                    path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST8000DM004-2CX188_ZR10RA7N-part1'
                    devid: 'ata-ST8000DM004-2CX188_ZR10RA7N-part1'
                    phys_path: 'pci-0000:01:00.1-ata-4.0'
                children[4]:
                    type: 'disk'
                    id: 4
                    guid: 260649952118180299
                    whole_disk: 1
                    create_txg: 4
                    path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST8000DM004-2U9188_ZR151F2J-part1'
                    devid: 'ata-ST8000DM004-2U9188_ZR151F2J-part1'
                    phys_path: 'pci-0000:08:00.0-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0'
            children[1]:
                type: 'raidz'
                id: 1
                guid: 240687314187761822
                nparity: 1
                metaslab_array: 641
                metaslab_shift: 34
                ashift: 9
                asize: 18003481067520
                is_log: 0
                create_txg: 5187619
                children[0]:
                    type: 'disk'
                    id: 0
                    guid: 10386202710927202705
                    whole_disk: 1
                    DTL: 22553
                    create_txg: 5187619
                    path: '/dev/sdg1'
                    devid: 'ata-WDC_WD60EZAZ-00SF3B0_WD-WX22DA15XS1Z-part1'
                    phys_path: 'pci-0000:0b:00.3-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0'
                children[1]:
                    type: 'disk'
                    id: 1
                    guid: 6384748657570502003
                    whole_disk: 1
                    DTL: 22552
                    create_txg: 5187619
                    path: '/dev/sdh1'
                    devid: 'ata-WDC_WD60EZAZ-00SF3B0_WD-WX32DA1APAD4-part1'
                    phys_path: 'pci-0000:0b:00.3-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:1'
                children[2]:
                    type: 'disk'
                    id: 2
                    guid: 4047734325973090233
                    whole_disk: 1
                    DTL: 22551
                    create_txg: 5187619
                    path: '/dev/sdi1'
                    devid: 'ata-WDC_WD6003FZBX-00K5WB0_V9K6YNSM-part1'
                    phys_path: 'pci-0000:0b:00.3-usb-0:4:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0'
        load-policy:
            load-request-txg: 18446744073709551615
            load-rewind-policy: 2
zdb: can't open 'video': No such device or address

ZFS_DBGMSG(zdb) START:
spa.c:6156:spa_import(): spa_import: importing video
spa_misc.c:416:spa_load_note(): spa_load(video, config trusted): LOADING
vdev_raidz.c:4588:vdev_raidz_init(): reflow_in_progress=0
vdev_raidz.c:4588:vdev_raidz_init(): reflow_in_progress=0
vdev.c:154:vdev_dbgmsg(): disk vdev '/dev/sdi1': probe done, cant_read=0 cant_write=1
vdev.c:154:vdev_dbgmsg(): disk vdev '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST8000DM004-2CX188_ZR10AXW8-part1': probe done, cant_read=0 cant_write=1
vdev.c:154:vdev_dbgmsg(): disk vdev '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST8000DM004-2CX188_ZR10AYT2-part1': probe done, cant_read=0 cant_write=1
vdev.c:154:vdev_dbgmsg(): disk vdev '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST8000DM004-2CX188_ZR10AXV1-part1': probe done, cant_read=0 cant_write=1
vdev.c:154:vdev_dbgmsg(): disk vdev '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST8000DM004-2CX188_ZR10RA7N-part1': probe done, cant_read=0 cant_write=1
vdev.c:154:vdev_dbgmsg(): disk vdev '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST8000DM004-2U9188_ZR151F2J-part1': probe done, cant_read=0 cant_write=1
vdev.c:154:vdev_dbgmsg(): disk vdev '/dev/sdh1': probe done, cant_read=0 cant_write=1
vdev.c:154:vdev_dbgmsg(): disk vdev '/dev/sdg1': probe done, cant_read=0 cant_write=1
vdev.c:154:vdev_dbgmsg(): disk vdev '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST8000DM004-2CX188_ZR10AYT2-part1': best uberblock found for spa video. txg 7803281
vdev.c:154:vdev_dbgmsg(): disk vdev '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST8000DM004-2CX188_ZR10AYT2-part1': spa=video best uberblock (txg=7803281 info=0x0) has different raidz_reflow_info than latest uberblock (txg=18446744073709547384 info=0x5621bd1f86b0)
spa_misc.c:402:spa_load_failed(): spa_load(video, config untrusted): FAILED: no valid uberblock found
spa_misc.c:416:spa_load_note(): spa_load(video, config untrusted): UNLOADING
ZFS_DBGMSG(zdb) END
```

Everything I'm finding in my searches seems to be just off slightly from my issue except for one that said it might just be gone because USB. All the listed drives are present and accounted for, and I double-checked that the ones for raidz1-1 are the correct drives.

Comment: This would be best asked on the [TrueNAS forum](https://www.truenas.com/community/) since they have engineers on the forum  and they're going to be more knowledgeable that most on StackExchange when it comes to ZFS _(Copy/paste as is into a post on the [forum](https://www.truenas.com/community/forums/operation-and-performance.153/), but add a sentence at the top this isn't a TrueNAS question, is a ZFS question)_